# Got error when application run in Huawei (device Specific issue)

Tags: android, soap, huawei-mobile-services

My application is working fine in all devices except Huawei device.  I am calling SOAP service using ksoap2 library.  But when I call service, It throw error.

I am using https for calling web service from android.

**Error Log**

```
00:10 W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
00:10 W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:76)
00:10 W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:153)
00:10 W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.ngha.sshr.LoginActivity$ValidateUserAsyncTask.callingValidateUser(LoginActivity.java:260)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.ngha.sshr.LoginActivity$ValidateUserAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:159)
00:10 W/System.err:     at com.ngha.sshr.LoginActivity$ValidateUserAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:141)
00:10 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:316)
00:10 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
00:10 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:255)
00:11 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
00:11 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
00:11 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
00:11 W/System.err:     Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
00:11 W/System.err:         ... 25 more
00:11 W/System.err:         Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
00:11 W/System.err:             ... 25 more
00:11 W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable.getPropertyCount()' on a null object reference
00:11 W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:521)
00:11 W/System.err:     at com.ngha.sshr.LoginActivity$ValidateUserAsyncTask.ParsingForValidateUser(LoginActivity.java:296)
00:11 W/System.err:     at com.ngha.sshr.LoginActivity$ValidateUserAsyncTask.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:182)
00:11 W/System.err:     at com.ngha.sshr.LoginActivity$ValidateUserAsyncTask.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:141)
00:11 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:688)
00:11 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
00:11 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:705)
00:11 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
00:11 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
00:11 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
00:11 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
00:11 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
00:11 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
```

Comment: There is a chance that Huawei, like HTC, has ksoap2 in their vendor libraries - in that case you'll have to use jarjar to rename your ksoap2 lib's classes to something like `com.myapp.org.ksoap` so they don't collide with the vendor one (because vendor libs are loaded first and last, preventing you to overwrite/replace/update it).

It's either that or you got a response which is null.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have renamed package in jar and use it.  But still same error..

Comment: Could you update the question with the new log and stacktrace? Can you wireshark the transmission to see what could be wrong when not using SSL ?